# I am getting the variable undefined error as I am defining the variable

Tags: python, variables, math, undefined

I'm new to python and have had this error continuously. I get the "variable undefined" error as I am defining the variable. c and d are the problems in this particular code:

```
    m = 1
while m == 1:
    studentname = input("What is the student's name?")
    testnumber = int(input("How many tests have they completed? (up to 10)"))
    while testnumber <= 0:
        print("Invalid.")
        testnumber = int(input("How many tests have they completed? (up to 10)"))
    while testnumber >= 10:
        print("Invalid.")
        testnumber = int(input("How many tests have they completed? (up to 10)"))
        while testnumber <= 0:
           print("Invalid.")
           testnumber = int(input("How many tests have they completed? (up to 10)"))
    if testnumber >= 1:
            a = int(input("What is their mark?"))
            b = int(input("Out of?"))
            c == a / b
            d == c * 100
            print("Their mark is", d, "percent.")
```

I want c to equal a divided by b, but the program claims that c is undefined, even as "c == a / b" defines what I want c to be. I have tried "a / b == c" and "a/ b == int(c)" but nothing works.

Comment: "even as "c == a / b" defines what I want c to be" In your own words, why do you expect `c == a / b` to cause `c` to become equal to the result of a divided by `b`? Hint: when you wished for `a` to become equal to the value input from the user, did you write `a == int(input("What is their mark?"))`? No, you did not. Look at the code more closely.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have double = signs which compares two variables instead of assigning them.

If you want to assign a value then you only need a single '='

Try this:

```
m = 1
while m == 1:
studentname = input("What is the student's name?")
testnumber = int(input("How many tests have they completed? (up to 10)"))
while testnumber <= 0:
    print("Invalid.")
    testnumber = int(input("How many tests have they completed? (up to 10)"))
while testnumber >= 10:
    print("Invalid.")
    testnumber = int(input("How many tests have they completed? (up to 10)"))
    while testnumber <= 0:
       print("Invalid.")
       testnumber = int(input("How many tests have they completed? (up to 10)"))
if testnumber >= 1:
        a = int(input("What is their mark?"))
        b = int(input("Out of?"))
        c = a / b
        d = c * 100
        print("Their mark is", d, "percent.")
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was missing something. This resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are using equality operator for assignment. As the variable c, d don't exist already, you are getting error.

```py
a = int(input("What is their mark?"))
b = int(input("Out of?"))
c == a / b  # problem here. Define it as c = a /b
d == c * 100 # problem here. Define it as d = c * 100
```

You can solve them by changing code as below:

```py
  if testnumber >= 1:
     a = int(input("What is their mark?"))
     b = int(input("Out of?"))
     c = a / b
     d = c * 100
     print("Their mark is", d, "percent.")
```

Comment: @user14245564, I have updated my answer with the fix, you have to apply. I have mentioned the problem also

Answer (score 1):

When you use `==` that means you are comparing the two variables.

For example, if you have `x==y` what you are doing is checking whether **x is equal to y or not**.

If you want to assign a value to a variable in your case c then you have to use a single `=` sign instead of `==`.

Therefore your code will look like:

```
 if testnumber >= 1:
            a = int(input("What is their mark?"))
            b = int(input("Out of?"))
            c = a / b
            d = c * 100
            print("Their mark is", d, "percent.")
```